# Why are elements not lining up horizontally

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I have a site that I'm trying to design and I have elements that need to line up horizontally, this isn't working correctly, though.  These elements are in a parent wrapper div and they are floated left and right respectively.  There is also an image div inside one of the elements that has text wrapping around it.  So far, I've been able to get the text to wrap around the image div correctly using floats, however, the other element on the page is not lining up correctly.

Here's a pen and accompanying code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbXpZz

**HTML**

```
<body>
        <header></header>

        <div id="page">
            <div id="image"></div>

            <section>
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu.</p>

                 <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </section>
            <aside>
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>

                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem - <span>Ipsum</span></li>
                    <li>Lorem - <span>Ipsum</span></li>
                </ul>
            <aside>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}

header, #image, #page{
    display: block;
}

header, #page, #image{
    float: left;
}

header, #page{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

header{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(171, 166, 27);
}

header ul{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: black;
}

header ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

#page{
    top: 150px;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
}

#image{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 3px outset rgb(171, 166, 27);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

section{
    display: block;
    float left;
    width: 80%;
    border-right: 3px solid rgb(171, 166, 27);
    background-color: blue;
}

section h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

section p{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

aside{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 18%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

If I change the section and aside to be inline-block, they line up, but they do so underneath the image.  Also, if I position the image div absolutely, everything lines up the way it should, but the text in the `section` no longer wraps around the image div.  Can anyone help?

Comment: how exactly do you want to line them up?

Comment: I want the aside element to line up horizontally to the right of the section element.  Not below it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work the way you want you need to change the order on your markup:

From:

```
<div id="image"></div>
<section></section>
<aside><aside>
```

To:

```
<div id="image"></div>
<aside><aside>
<section></section>
```

Floated Elements First to ensure the block behavior of `section` doesn't affect the flow of the floated elements.

#### [CodepenDemo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEaBYK)

Comment: Thank you.  It's been a while since I've done CSS, guess I forgot that rule.

Comment: @Robert glad to help U